# CAFAudioDescription member types and endian-ness

Tags: objective-c, c, core-audio, endianness

`CAFAudioDescription`'s `mSampleRate` member is a `Float64` type, but to assign it a value like 44100.0, I need to convert it to big-endian first. The function `CFConvertFloat64HostToSwapped` returns a `CFSwappedFloat64` which is a `uint64_t`, not `Float64`.

Why does it return an int type? I cannot even cast it as `Float64`.

```
    // required file header
    CAFFileHeader fileHeader;
    fileHeader.mFileType = CFSwapInt32HostToBig('caff');
    fileHeader.mFileVersion = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(1);
    fileHeader.mFileFlags = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(0);

    // required chunk header for audio description chunk below
    CAFChunkHeader audioHeader;
    audioHeader.mChunkType = CFSwapInt32HostToBig('desc');
    audioHeader.mChunkSize = sizeof(CAFAudioDescription);

    // required first chunk
    CAFAudioDescription audioChunk;
    audioChunk.mSampleRate = CFConvertFloat64HostToSwapped(44100.0); // type mismatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change endianness, the value no longer makes sense to host system. It is just a bunch of bits.

There is no reason why you couldn't store those bits to any type that can hold 64-bits, even `Float64`.

However, endianness swap is often done with bit-shifting and masking, and since unsigned integer types are most suitable for the job (you cannot do it with floats), the bit pattern is likely assigned to `uint64_t` before the operation.

You could move bits back to float type after the operation, but it would be extra step and value wouldn't make sense anyway.

Signed integer conversion doesn't have to be converted to unsigned integer first, as bit operations work with them. It would be good to do so for API consistency though, as numeric value on swapped signed integer doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Thanks. Any clue as to how I would assign uint64_t to Float64 without a compile error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm only a beginner with Objective-C, and I haven't used this API, but:

The uint64_t is just so it is 64 bits of something. What is stored in those 64 bits is not an integer, though, but the converted Float64. It doesn't have the type Float64, since it *isn't* a Float64, but a *converted* Float64.

Comment: but the other fields are converted as well but stored in the same type. Why only the float?